# Add Items to top of recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a Recyclerview in my activity. when I pull down it will load new items to recycle view.
Now I need to implement pull to refresh the concept to my recyclerview. I have done that. But when I call pull to refresh I am getting new items and added to recycle view bottom. I required to add new items to top of my recycle view. How can I add new loaded items to the top position of recycler view.

```
 public void refreshing() throws IllegalStateException{

    new AsyncTask<String, Void, Void>() {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String... arg0) {
                final List<NameValuePair> list = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                list.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", sPreferences.getString("ID", "")));

                final HttpParams httpParams = new BasicHttpParams();
                HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParams, 30000);
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParams);
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(Config.requestpatienthistory);
                httpPost.getParams().setBooleanParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.USE_EXPECT_CONTINUE, false);
                try {
                    httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(list));
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                try {                       
                    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
                    String json = reader.readLine();


                    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(json);
                    if (jsonObj.has("control")) {

                        JSONArray feedArray = jsonObj.getJSONArray("control");
                        for (int i = 0; i < feedArray.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject feedObj = (JSONObject) feedArray.get(i);

                            final Historyitem item = new Historyitem();

                            if (feedObj.has("Reported_Time")) {                                 
                                  item.setReported_Time(feedObj.getString("Reported_Time"));                                
                            }
                            historyitems.add(item);
                        }
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("" + "no patients");
                    }
                } catch (SocketException e) {
                   e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();                    
                }             
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            historyadapter = new HistoryRecycleListAdapter(getActivity(), getActivity(), historyitems);
            hisrecyclerview.setAdapter(historyadapter);                                                
        }
    }.execute();
}
```

Answer (score 30):

I would insist you to add item at `0th` position which is coming from pull to refresh as below,

```
mArrayList.add(position, item);
notifyItemInserted(position);
```

Comment: I understand this quite alright but my question is..
when i do a pull to refresh, the data received can have two states.. either there are new items which aren't already existing on the list or the old items have some update. will notifyItemInserted solve this issue.. im trying so hard not to use notifyDatasetChanged();..Please

Comment: @PaulOkeke This answer is not related to your question, so its better to post another question & seek for answer!

Answer (score 8):

Add following line when you set your recyclerview

```
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context,LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL,true));
```

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that, but I like it. Thanks.

Comment: This saved my day.

Answer (score 6):

I also need to add items to the front of recyclerview(and to bottom), but i need to keep scroll focused at the previous top item.

So i'm scrolling recyclerview to previous top item:

```
mAdapter.pushFront(items);
mAdapter.notifyItemRangeInserted(0, items.size());
recyclerView.scrollToPosition(items.size() - 1);
```

Is there a better solution?

Comment: Here should be answers not questions!

Answer (score 3):

You can reverse your whole list using Collections :

```
Collections.reverse(historyitems);
```

Try using adapter :

```
adapter.insert(yourItem, 0);
```

Try using List :

```
list.add(0,listItem);
```

Comment: I need to add only newly added items to top

Answer (score 3):

use `list.add(0,items);` it will add new item to top of recyclerview

Answer (score 3):

in Recyclerview you also set your list order. you just set your adapter to reverse true or false.

```
RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager=newLinearLayoutManager(this,LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL,true);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
```

after set layout manager to your Recyclerview Adapter.
And if you want to perform delete some item view on your recyclerview also you need to add

```
layoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
```

Answer (score 3):

Do it in xml you don't need `LinearLayoutManager` code anymore

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recordItemList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        app:layoutManager="LinearLayoutManager"
        app:stackFromEnd="true"
        app:reverseLayout="true"/>
```

Comment: Appreacite, the attributes did the trick.

Comment: `app:stackFromEnd="true"` and `app:reverseLayout="true"` did the trick, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

When you pull to refresh your data then you can simply reverse your list like this:

```
Collections.reverse(yourModelList);
notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Answer (score 0):

Recycler view has nothing to with ordering of items. From the above code you are refreshing contents and simply displaying what you are getting from server. May be the items returned from server are in the order they get displayed. So check the order from server what you are getting.

Comment: When I call this function each time I am getting new values. and these values added to bottom of recycling view. but I need to add these items to top. For example, when we scroll to down "Fb" if new news comes it will display at the top of the list view. Like that when I this function I need to add new items to top of recycle view.

Comment: modify your add/append method in adapter. Whenever you are adding values to the Collection do it like   public void appendData(ArrayList newData){  newData.addAll(origData); origData = newData; notifyDatasetChanged(); } This way you ensure that all your newely added items will appear first then the old ones.

Answer (score 0):

For perfect control position system, **add each item's position** in arraylist. For new item position will be 0. Use Comparator and sort items by using Collection Class.

```
 Collections.sort(arrayOfPosts, new SortPostByPosition()); 
 listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Here is **SortPostByPosition** class that compare position of each item.

```
class SortPostByPosition implements Comparator<TimelineListData> {
    public int compare(TimelineListData a, TimelineListData b) {
        return Integer.compare(a.position, b.position);
        // you can compare by your own complex formula too
    }
}
```