# RecyclerView: new loaded items will not be added to top

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-recyclerview, adapter

I am receiving new item data from server and set it to adapter of my RecyclerView. When I first start the async-task to get data then the fetched data is displayed from top. But when I start async-task again to get new data then the new data is attached below the (invisible) old ones, although I am setting `adapter = null` before I start server request.

General Process:

1) start Activity and AsyncTask to get data from server: `asynctask.execute();`

2) call `mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);` and `mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` and data will be shown from top on

3) initate asynctask again: first set `mAdapter = null;` and load another data

**Problem in 3):** now new loaded data will not be shown from top on, rather below the data that were there in 1) but no more visible because of `mAdapter = null;`. It is like RecyclerView did not "delete" the space of the old data that were shown in 1).

This is weird, has somebody any idea why this behavior occurs?

---

Code:

a) My Adapter:

```
public class Adapter_New extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Adapter_New.CustomViewHolder> {

    private List<Data_B> feedItemList;
    private Context mContext;
    private int lastPosition = -1, b_height;
    int width, height, targetHeight;
    private ViewHolderState viewHolderState = ViewHolderState.getInstance();


    public Adapter_New(Context context, List<Data_B> feedItemList) {
        this.feedItemList = feedItemList;
        this.mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public CustomViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {

        DisplayMetrics metrics = mContext.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();

        int calc_width= metrics.widthPixels;
        int calc_height=metrics.heightPixels;
        int dens=metrics.densityDpi;
        double wi=(double)calc_width/(double)dens;
        double hi=(double)calc_height/(double)dens;
        double x = Math.pow(wi,2);
        double y = Math.pow(hi,2);
        double screenInches = Math.sqrt(x + y);

        if (screenInches >= 7.0){
            width = metrics.widthPixels/3;
            height = metrics.heightPixels / 4;
        }else{
            width = metrics.widthPixels/2;
            height = metrics.heightPixels / 4;
        }


        View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item_grid, null);
        CustomViewHolder viewHolder = new CustomViewHolder(view);


        return viewHolder;
    }


    @Override
    public void onViewDetachedFromWindow(CustomViewHolder holder) {
        super.onViewDetachedFromWindow(holder);
        ((CustomViewHolder) holder).clearAnimation();
        ((CustomViewHolder) holder).cleanup();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final CustomViewHolder customViewHolder, int i) {

        Data_Borrow data = feedItemList.get(i);

        final Target target = new Target() {

            @Override
            public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
                b_height = bitmap.getHeight();

                customViewHolder.frame.getLayoutParams().height = b_height; //setting height dynamically
                customViewHolder.imageView.getLayoutParams().height = b_height; //setting height dynamically
                customViewHolder.imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            }

            @Override
            public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable) {
            }


        };

        customViewHolder.imageView.setTag(target);

        Picasso.with(mContext)
                .load(data.getImageUrl())
                .resize(width, height)
                .into(target);

        // Animation apply
        setAnimation(customViewHolder.rel_container, i);

    }

    //Animation
    private void setAnimation(View viewToAnimate, int position) {
        // If the bound view wasn't previously displayed on screen, it's animated
        if (position > lastPosition) {
            Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(mContext, R.anim.slide_in_up);
            viewToAnimate.startAnimation(animation);
            lastPosition = position;
        }
    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return (null != feedItemList ? feedItemList.size() : 0);
    }


    public void add_new(List<Data_Borrow> datas) {

        //feedItemList.clear();
        feedItemList.addAll(datas);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void clear() {

        feedItemList.clear();
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }


    public class CustomViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        protected ImageView imageView;
        protected RelativeLayout rel_container;
        protected FrameLayout frame;
        protected CardView card_view;

        public CustomViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            this.imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
            this.title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
            this.rel_container = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.rel_grid_item);
            this.frame = (FrameLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.frame_current);
            this.frame.getLayoutParams().width = width; //setting width dynamically
            this.card_view = (CardView) view.findViewById(R.id.card_view);

        }

        public void cleanup() {
            Picasso.with(mContext)
                    .cancelRequest(imageView);
        }


        public void clearAnimation() {
            rel_container.clearAnimation();
        }
    }
}
```

b) My Activity:

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements FetchDataListener, SearchView.OnQueryTextListener, AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {

 private List<Data_B> feedsList = null;
 private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
 private Adapter_New mAdapter;
 StaggeredGridLayoutManager StaggeredGridLayoutManager;


        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.my_activity);

         StaggeredGridLayoutManager = new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(3, 1);
         StaggeredGridLayoutManager.setGapStrategy(StaggeredGridLayoutManager.GAP_HANDLING_NONE);
         mRecyclerView.setAdapter(new Data_Borrow_Adapter_New(this, feedsList)); // first add empty adapter
         mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(StaggeredGridLayoutManager);

         initView(); //start initView when activity starts

        //******* WHEN I CLICK TO GET NEW FILTERED DATA, then new data is not shown from top on ****//       
        btn_start_filtered_asynctask = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_filter);
        btn_start_filtered_asynctask.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
              initViewFilterd();
            }
        });

    }


    private void initView() {

        String url = "http://xxx/xx.php";
        String show_from = "0";

        FetchDataTask_ALL task = new FetchDataTask_ALL(this);
        task.execute(url, show_from);

        loading = true;

    }

    private void initViewFilterd() {

        String url = "http://xxx/xx.php";
        String show_from = "0";
        String result_category_pos = "2";

        FetchDataTask_Filtered task = new FetchDataTask_Filtered(this);
        task.execute(url, result_category_pos, show_from);

        mAdapter = null; //setting adapter null 

        loading = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onFetchComplete(List<Data_B> data) {

    if (mAdapter == null) 

            {
                mAdapter = new Adapter_New(getApplicationContext(), data);
                mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
                mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            } else {

                mAdapter.add_new(data);

            }

        searchItem.collapseActionView();
        loading = false;
        mRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    }

}
```

Comment: Could you add relevant code instead of vague descriptions?

Comment: ok I included my activity and my adapter. Please see updated question.

Comment: Why did you comment `feedItemList.clear()` in `add_new`?

Comment: I actually implemented loadmore behavior, so when I scroll to the end then new data will be added. I cutted the class to the relevant parts. So, I comment `feedItemList.clear()` because the new data should be added to the "old" ones.

Comment: So your question is not clear anymore. Maybe have a look at [`setReverseLayout()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/LinearLayoutManager.html#setReverseLayout%28boolean%29)

Comment: My problem is similar to that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32003402/add-items-to-top-of-recyclerview]...but how can I use it in my code? sorry  I am still beginner...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should not set adapter to null, you should update the data in the adapter (in your case, add the new item at the beginning of the datasource (list, array, anything) and then call `notifyDataSetChanged()`

EDIT: I suggest to change this two methods: remove adapter = null, and always add item first. (you may need to add that method to the adapter)

```
private void initViewFilterd() {
    String url = "http://xxx/xx.php";
    String show_from = "0";
    String result_category_pos = "2";

    FetchDataTask_Filtered task = new FetchDataTask_Filtered(this);
    task.execute(url, result_category_pos, show_from);

    loading = true;
}

@Override
public void onFetchComplete(List<Data_B> data) {
    mAdapter.addFirstAndUpdate(data);

    searchItem.collapseActionView();
    loading = false;
    mRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

}
```

In adapter:

```
public void addFirstAndUpdate(List<Data_Borrow> datas) {
    // TODO: add data in feedItemList
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: thanks for the hint, I removed `adapter = null;` and now filtered data is shown from top... but how can I now check in `onFetchComplete` if adapter is empty or not?

Comment: You can add a method in the adapter that checks for feedItemList.isEmpty(), but.. why?