# How do I place new items at the top of a recyclerView?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I'm adding content to my database (**Firebase**) which are suppose to be loaded into my recyclerview. But the new content always appear at the bottom of the recyclerview. Is there any way to make them appear at the top rather than appear at the bottom

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add Items to top of recyclerview](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32003402/add-items-to-top-of-recyclerview)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved the issue all i needed to do was to initialize an integer variable as 0,add it along side with the  object of the model class that is to be gotten from the Firebase database and finally notifying an item inserted to the adapter.The code will explain better

```
int position = 0;
ArrayList<Places> data = new ArrayList<>();
LinearLayoutManager lg = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
```

then the final code was this

```
valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
@Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
Places content = ds.getValue(Places.class);
    data.add(position,content);
adapter = new YourAdapter(data, getApplicationContext);
      recyclerview.setLayoutManager(new Line);
      recyclerview.setAdapter(adapter);
      adapter.notifyItemInserted(position);
       adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
@Override
public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
     // Handle error code here
   }
     });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to appear new Items on the top just Add this code in your Activity.
you need to reverse your RecyclerView, then you totally need this code segment. It does not require any modification or any special library. It’s so simple to work on LinearLayoutManager .

```
 LinearLayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        mLayoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);
        mLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
```

First you need to create a LinearLayoutManager object and use “setReverseLayout(true)” and “setStackFromEnd(true)” methods to reverse and add item at the end.

Comment: i created an object of LinearLayoutManager but couldn't find any option for `.setReverseLayout(true);` or `.setStackFromEnd(true);`

Comment: @XY-JOE there is two layout manager do not use this RecyclerView.LayoutManager instead use this LinearLayoutManager.

Answer (score 0):

Just add these lines in your

```java
LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager=new LinearLayoutManager(this);
linearLayoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);
linearLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
```

still not worked then add this in .xml

```xml
app:reverseLayout="true"
app:stackFromEnd="true"
```