# How to show newest items on top in firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a data base reference and in that I have the details of the announcement, but actually when a new announcement is added to the existing database, it gets displayed way below the last element, I want it to be on the top.

Here is the code for reading announcement from DB

```
 demo= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("IDS").child("/News");


    demo.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for(DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                RvClass rvClass = snapshot.getValue(RvClass.class);
                list.add(rvClass);

            }
            CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(SubmitNews.this,list);
            rv.setAdapter(adapter);

        }


       @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

After fetching the data I displayed it in a RecyclerView , all functionality is fine except the newly added announcement, it is getting placed at the last.

Thank you!

Comment: Searching for [firebase android newest on top](https://www.google.com/search?q=site:stackoverflow.com+firebase+android+newest+on+top) gives some good results. Most seem based around reversing the layout manager and stacking it from the top as shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43321791/209103

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using `limitToLast()`
**Example of `limitToLast()`**

```
  demo = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("IDS").child("/News");
     Query query = demo.orderByKey().limitToLast(15);
     query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        RvClass rvClass = snapshot.getValue(RvClass.class);
                        list.add(rvClass);

                    }
                    CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(SubmitNews.this, list);
                    rv.setAdapter(adapter);

                }


                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
```

Also please check below link this will help you.
[Firebase Data Desc Sorting in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34156996/firebase-data-desc-sorting-in-android)

Comment: It is giving me the same order , i want the order in which we can fetch newest item first!

Comment: please check my updated answer.