# How can I add data into Room database in a manner where it is appended to the top row

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

[Image for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1o8g8.png)

I am facing a situation whenever I add a new article into the database it will add the new article to the bottom of the RecyclerView, how can I implement it in such a way that it updates the top row instead?

Is it something got to do with the `Adapter` or do I have to tweak the `Doa`?

**Room Database Implementation**

```
**//ViewModel**
fun saveArticle(article: Article) = viewModelScope.launch {
        newsRepository.upsert(article)
    }

**
//NewsRepository**
suspend fun upsert(article: Article) = db.getArticleDao().upsert(article)


**//Implementation of the Database**
@Database(
    entities = [Article::class],
    version = 1
)

@TypeConverters(Converters::class)
abstract class ArticleDatabase : RoomDatabase() {

    abstract fun getArticleDao(): ArticleDao

    companion object {
        @Volatile
        private var instance: ArticleDatabase? = null
        private val LOCK = Any()
       
        operator fun invoke(context: Context) = instance ?: synchronized(LOCK) {
            instance ?: createDatabase(context).also { instance = it }
        }
        private fun createDatabase(context: Context) =
            Room.databaseBuilder(
                context.applicationContext,
                ArticleDatabase::class.java,
                "article_db.db"
            ).build()
    }
}


**//DOA**
@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    suspend fun upsert(article: Article): Long //returns the id's of the article

**//Entity**
@Entity(
    tableName = "articles", indices = [Index(value = ["url","title"], unique = true)]
)
@Parcelize
data class Article(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    var id: Int? =null,
    val author: String?,
    val description: String?,
    val source: Source?,
    val title: String?,
    val url: String?,
    val urlToImage: String?,
    val publishedAt: String?,
    val content: String?
): Parcelable {
    override fun hashCode(): Int {
        var result = id.hashCode()
        if(url.isNullOrEmpty()){
            result = 31 * result + url.hashCode()
        }
        return result
    }
}
```

Expecting the top row to be updated instead of the bottom row, the Room Database docs did not talk much about changing the way the article is inserted, tried to reference other people's work, couldn't find the solution

Comment: What is your code for rendering the list of articles? That is where the changes should be made.

Comment: If you want your query results to be sorted a particular way, include an `ORDER BY` clause in the query.

Comment: You need to order the list descending by id. `select * from articles order by id desc `. This way whenever you add a new item and fetch all articles again, the latest inserted item will go to the top.

Comment: It very well may be the Adapter. It sounds like you are getting the new data just fine, but the recycler view is adding it to the bottom. Try the 0th position instead for the new element:

```mArrayList.add(position, item);
notifyItemInserted(position);
```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32003402/add-items-to-top-of-recyclerview